# Model Class response issue

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a Model class

```
data class OtpVerifyModel(
val result: Int? = null,
val msg: String? = null,
val data: Datas? = null)
```

in the response success stage, result is equal to 1 and we get Object in data where as if result is -1. we get string in data part. I used Datas class for data but app crashes in a case when data is a string. How can I handle two different type of data in same variable in different cases?
here is my retrofit method

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Api/login")
suspend fun verifyOtp(
    @Query("height") height: String,
    @Query("width") width: String,
    @Field("key") key: String,
    @Field("type") type: String,
    @Field("phone") phone: String,
    @Field("email") email: String,
    @Field("otp") otp: String,
    @Field("country_code") country_code: String,
    @Field("country_flag") country_flag: String
): Response<OtpVerifyModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a basic API response using the generic class that takes a type as T for different data types like the below :

```
data class ApiResponse<T>(
    val data: T?,
    val result: Int? = null,
    val msg: String? = null,
)
```

then you can have a class for success state :

```
data class verifyOtp(
     val result: String?,
     ...
)
```

and pass this class to ApiResponse :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Api/login")
suspend fun verifyOtp(
    @Query("height") height: String,
    @Query("width") width: String,
    @Field("key") key: String,
    @Field("type") type: String,
    @Field("phone") phone: String,
    @Field("email") email: String,
    @Field("otp") otp: String,
    @Field("country_code") country_code: String,
    @Field("country_flag") country_flag: String
): Response<ApiResponse<verifyOtp>>
```

this way your data will be `verifyOtp` when the result is successful.
in the case of error, based on how you implemented the repository class you can parse the response. be careful that in case of error the API should return a status code different than 200 that you can parse in the repository.